# calculus engine in vb?

Tags: vb.net

is there an easy to use library or engine for .NET that does calculus?

Comment: Just to clarify, you mean symbolic differentiation / integration / etc., not numerical methods, right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I posted an early version of some code I used in one of my classes in an answer to this thread:

[Generated methods for polynomial evaluation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1631369/generated-methods-for-polynomial-evaluation) (my answer includes classes for symbolic differentiation)

If I know exactly what you're looking for, I could try to post an updated version.

Comment: Someone voted me down without reading my answer in that link.

Comment: Yea, they sometimes do that. don't sweat it, it's just rep.

Answer (score 1):

Google is suggesting you look through [Wikipedia's list](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Automatic_differentiation#Software) of free libraries that can do [automatic differentiation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Automatic_differentiation), and see if any have a .NET or COM wrapper. **EDIT**: High-Performance Mark has pointed out that it appears you need symbolic differentiation, in which case these libraries won't help.

If you are keen, you possibly could create a .NET wrapper for one of the C++ libraries.